# Fluent Nhibernate NonUniqueObjectException during one transaction

Tags: exception, transactions, fluent-nhibernate, unique

I've stucked with NonUniqueObjectException exception working with fluent nhibernate.
 I've got a cycle working with some business logics, cheching presence of some data in db. If the data is not it DB, it should be added. But all operations within this cycle are made in the same transaction.
 This is how cycle body looks like:

```
 // Open session, start transaction
 if(!_service.CheckIfEntityInDb(entity))
 {
   entity = new entity() {var1 = value1, var2 = value2};
   _service.SaveOrUpdate(entity);
 }
```

I've alredy tried to use `merge`, but merging return me entity with empty fiels. This entity is kind of mapping, and consist only of two properties of other entities types.
Pls give some advice of solving this issue, except of commiting data every step of cycle.
Thanks.

**UPDATE**:

```
public bool CheckIfEntityInDb(entity)
{
  Session.QueryOver<Entity>.Where(x => x.Id == entity.Id).Future().FirstOrDefault();
}

public bool CheckIfEntityInDb(entity)
{
  Session.SaveOrUpdate(entity);
}
```

Comment: show the code for `CheckIfEntityInDb(entity)` and which Flushmode you use plz.

Comment: who does generate the id you are checking for?

Comment: @Firo, it's `Identity.GenereatedBy()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming you are generating the id yourself

```
var entity = session.Get<Entity>(someid); // this uses the firstlevel cache

if (entity == null)
{
    entity = new Entity { Id = someid, var1 = value1, var2 = value2 };
    session.Save(entity);
}
```

### Update after generated by identity:

since you use identity the session knows which id is saved and which not. `session.SaveOrUpdate(entity);` will do nothing if the entity is known and issues an insert immediatly when it is a new entity

Comment: But, what it id is db generated?

Comment: On your comment, that the deal, than SaveOrUpdate throws non unique exception. And I don't know why.

Comment: then you are creating new entities with a valid id instead of session.Get<Entity>(id); which get the existing entities

Comment: So you think I should check it with `session.Get` and if nothing is returned then SaveOrUpdate?

Comment: `Save` because update would be meaningless if the entity does not exist in the db.

Comment: Thanks, Session.Get really saved me a lot of time.